# mode values under a categorical column in python appear in form of a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using this code to get the mode of a categorical column:

```
df.groupby('user_id')['product'].agg(pd.Series.mode).reset_index().rename(columns = {'product': 'most_used_product'}).astype(str)
```

after running the above code, values under this column appear in a form of list per user like:

```
['hat' 'shirt' 'shoes']
['hat' 'shoes']
['shirt']
```

when I try to select the value of column using:

```
df[df['most_used_product']== "['hat' 'shirt' 'shoes']"
```

I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax. How can I select the value of column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hav two errors, first the ending square bracket, second your data type is not string, use:

```
df[df['most_used_product'].astype(str)== "['hat', 'shirt', 'shoes']"]
```